# Creating PDB out of DLL

Tags: c++, debugging, pdb-files

I'm debugging an application that loads DLLs I didn't compile, but they have some exported functions.

Is it possible to generate PDBs from the DLLs so I will be able to see the exported functions symbols in the call stack during debug?

Thanks!

Comment: No.  Contact the owner of the DLL for a .pdb file, it is quite normal to have one provided with the license.

Comment: The whole point of a PDB file is to provide more debugging information than the DLL file provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdb is generated by compiler while generating code. You have not enough information to generate `pdb` from already compiled `dll` without access to its source code.

But often pdbs are provided by `dll`'s authors

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :-). So how do I know if one of the functions in the call stack is an exported function?

Comment: You actually still know exported function names (otherwise you would fail linking them by name), but you unable to get known 'deeper' function names